# juego de pases python

Tags: python

necesito ayuda con un ejercicio en el que me quedé atorado, básicamente lo que debería hacer el programa es que dado cierto rango y teniendo como inicio cierto valor y numero de pases vuelva al inicio si el numero de pases excede, así sucesivamente hasta que pases sea 0.

Dejo el enunciado: El programa consiste en un juego de pases. Cada jugador tiene un numero del 1 a N y están posicionados a la derecha del otro(1,2,3,4,5...N) formando un circulo. El numero 1 está posicionado a la derecha del N.
Un pase se hace al jugador que esté a la derecha (de uno en uno).

Se tiene tres valores por entrada: N que representa el numero de jugadores, K representa el numero del jugador que empieza el juego, P representa el numero de pases.
Por salida se debe imprimir el numero del jugador que dado P pases se queda con el juego.

```
Ejemplos de entrada y salida:
N=10 K=4 P=6 Salida:10
N=10 K=4 P=1 Salida:5
N=10 K=7 P=9 Salida:6
N=1  K=1 P=1001 Salida:1
```

No dejo código porque no tengo idea de como resolverlo y no me quiero quedar con la duda, si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradezco de antemano.

Comment: Mmm... interesante tengo una idea pero la eficiencia estaría por los suelos

Answer (score 2):

Esto es algo rústico pero cumple con las entradas y salidas

```
N=int(input("ingresar número de jugadores(N): "))
K=int(input("ingresar número de jugador inicial(K): "))
P=int(input("ingresar número de pases(P): "))
S=K

while P>0:
    # Pasar al jugador siguiente
    # Si llegamos al jugador N, en su lugar lo pasará a 1
    S= S<=N-1 and S+1 or 1;
    # Disminuir el conteo de Pases restantes
    P=P-1;

print(f"Salida = {S}")
```

Comment: Funciona. Muchas gracias.